# How to create a SharePoint List where my colleagues can only add, edit or delete records (their own or somebody elses)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, permissions, administration, modern-experience

How can I create a SharePoint List where my colleagues can only add, edit or delete records.

Their own or somebody elses. But when I create a list my colleagues can also customize the list f.e: Adding new columns, sorting and filtering and grouping, or create new views. And I don't want that.

Is their a way to create a list so that someone else only can add, edit, or delete records (their own or somebody elses)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign **Contribute** permissions to users.

Contribute permission level:

> Enables users to manage personal views, edit items and user information, delete versions in existing lists and document libraries, and add, remove, and update personal Web Parts.

For more information about SharePoint permissions levels, check this: [User permissions and permission levels in SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/user-permissions-and-permission-levels)